# Plot cities in tableau from longitude and latitude

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, tableau-api, geocoding

I had JSON files which I cleaned and exported as csv files to be used in Tableau. The files have Longitude and Latitude fields, but I want to group them in Tableau by cities. How can I do so whether directly in Tableau or using Python?

Comment: what data and code do you have so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use geopy!!

https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")

location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")

print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union

print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)

print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '654513', 'osm_type': 'node', ...}
```